# jQuery Autocomplete: Hitting return submits the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery Autocomplete plugin.

```
// I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this

var base_url = window.location.href.slice(0, window.location.href.indexOf('/bar'));
$('.foo-widget').find('input:first-child').autocomplete(base_url + "/api/baz?format=newline");
```

The markup:

```
<ul class="foo-widget">
    <li>
        <input value="" autocomplete="off" class="ac_input"><input value="" autocomplete="off" class="ac_input"><button>Add</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This works fine. However, when I hit "enter" to choose an item from the autocomplete results, the form submits. Why might this be happening?

I looked into **jquery.autocomplete.js** and saw that the following is being executed:

```
        case KEY.RETURN:
            if( selectCurrent() ) {
                // stop default to prevent a form submit, Opera needs special handling
                event.preventDefault();
                blockSubmit = true;
                return false;
            }
            break;
```

Shouldn't `event.preventDefault()` and `blockSubmit = true` stop the form from submitting? Is it possible that JS code I have elsewhere on the page is interfering?

Comment: You could have another javascript error that is occurring before it gets to the preventDefault() code. Does Firebug show any errors?

Comment: Return false blocks the submit.

Comment: how many forms do you have in that page?

Comment: @aSeptik only one form. @Jared Farrish Firebug is not showing any errors.

Comment: Rosarch, please post the snippet if you found solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding an keypress event on the Autocomplete element and return false from that.  It will not impact your ability to submit the rest of the form at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to disable submission on enter by hooking up an event handler for form.submit: $("form").submit(function() {
  return false;
});

Comment: But I don't want to always disable the form submit - I only want it to be disabled when the user is hitting "return" on autocomplete results.