# jquery-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete

when I hit "enter" to choose an item from the  jquery-autocomplete  results, the form submits. Why this happens....

i should get the data in the text field and on second enter the form should submit...

please suggest where to change in autocomplete.js

Thanks in advance

Comment: r u using this [code](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Find the keydown event on the li,  in the autocomplete.js file and then place this line at the end of the keydown`s event handler (it may have some switch statement, you are interested about the 13[ enter key code]),:

```
return false;
```

ex:

```
.keydown(function(e) {
    // track last key pressed
    lastKeyPressCode = e.keyCode;
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 38: // up
            e.preventDefault();
            moveSelect(-1);
            break;
        case 40: // down
            e.preventDefault();
            moveSelect(1);
            break;
        case 9:  // tab
        case 13: // return
            if( selectCurrent() ){
                // make sure to blur off the current field
                $input.get(0).blur();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;          // ADD THIS !
            }

            break;
        default:
            active = -1;
            if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){onChange();}, options.delay);
            break;
    }
})
```

this will stop the event to further propagate and submit the form.

Comment: case KEY.RETURN:
            if( selectCurrent() ) {
                // stop default to prevent a form submit, Opera needs special handling
                event.preventDefault();
                blockSubmit = true;
                return false;
            }
            break;  I HAD THIS...BUT I DONT KNOW WHERE TO MODIFY I TRIED BY COMMENTING THE LINES BUT NO USE :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881401/jquery-autocomplete-hitting-return-submits-the-form      mine is the same case

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794688/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-prevent-form-submit and http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-combobox-problem-when-it-is-placed-inside-a-form-tag